# Discord.py Create Roles with given colour

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to work on a command, which creates roles and sets up everything (name, color and permissions)

I'm stuck at the point, where i can give the command a hex code for the colour

```
@client.command()
async def newrole(ctx, *, name, colour: discord.Colour()):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name, colour, permissions = discord.Permissions(104188992))
```

example command:

"?newrole Testing 0062ff" (if it could work with "Blue" instead of the hex/int value, that would be great as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When typehinting the arguments you don't call the class

```py
async def newrole(ctx, name, colour: discord.Colour): # Without the `()`
    # ...
```

It's also going to work when you type a color, e.g `blue`

Also you need to pass the arguments in `create_role` as kwargs:

```py
await guild.create_role(name=name, colour=colour, permissions=discord.Permissions(...))
```